# Why doesn't the blinking cursor appear when my edittext is enabled?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

I have a button and an EditText and when I press the button, the cursor should appear in the EditText and the soft keyboard should be displayed. I already tried a bunch of suggestion from SO, but nothing worked. Here is my logic so far:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/typed_word"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/word_list"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/type_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and when the button is pressed, this is what happens in the EditText:

```
    start_timer_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            assert inputMgr != null;
            inputMgr.showSoftInput(typed_word, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            reset_button.setEnabled(true);
            typed_word.requestFocus();
            word_list.setText("");
            typed_word.setText("");
            typed_word.setEnabled(true);
            text_str = "";
            start_timer_button.setEnabled(false);
            enableSettings = false;
        }
    });
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've been puzzling over this for two days.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the only way I was able to solve this was by creating a custom cursor:

custom_cursor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <size android:width="3dp" />
  <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"  />
</shape>
```

and

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/typed_word"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/word_list"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/type_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```